# Login in Android app with Gmail credentials

Tags: android, gmail, accountmanager

After getting the auth Token how to use it to login with google credentials

```
 AccountManager am=AccountManager.get(this); 
 Account[] accounts= am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
 account=accounts[0];
 amf = am.getAuthToken(account,"com.google", true,  
        new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {  
   public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {  

                try {  
                    Bundle result;  
                    Intent i;  
                    String token;  

                    result = arg0.getResult();  
        if (result.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {  
                        i = (Intent)result.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);  
                        System.out.println("INtect=="+i.toString());
                        if (i.toString().contains("GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity")) {  

                            cbt.startActivity(i);  
                            System.out.println("ssstttt");
                        } else {  
                            cbt.startActivity(i);
                            System.out.println("endddddd");
                        }  

                    } else {       
 token = (String)result.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

I have got the generated API key from google Account,but where to send the authToken and API key so that user can login using his gmail credentials

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended using Gmail credentials, since Google+ and Gmail is merged, what you actually want, is to be able to login with Google+. This will also make you able to make API calls.

Read more implementing Google+ sign in, in your app [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)

Comment: What do you mean by `not recommended'? Why can't a person be free to use or not use google plus along with gmail?