# Login using Gmail credentials

Tags: android, gmail, google-plus

Is there a way I can use Google credentials to get basic user info like

> Email, Name, Gender

and use them in my application? Its like allowing user to login into my application using Gmail.

I asked the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105751/enable-gmail-login-in-my-application).

But the answer says:

> You should not use Gmail for user authentication using Google
>   accounts. You can use Google + Sign-in for Android instead. This will
>   allow you to access the user's profile information upon getting the
>   required permissions using OAuth. Check out the guide here:

which i followed and everything worked fine.

**But if a Gmail account has no GooglePlus profile, My application asks to create a GooglePlus account. Which makes me think I implemented a GooglePlus Login instead of Gmail Login.**

**Is the answer for my other question right? Meaning without a GooglePlus profile you cannot have a Gmail Login in Android?**

If not how can I have a Google Login in my application?

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309093/login-in-android-app-with-gmail-credentials), with no replies.

Please help. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try article on this  Url : http://nilvec.com/implementing-smtp-or-imap-xoauth-authentication-in-java.html.

I think this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for using Google's OAuth2 to authenticate a user are provided at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login. As the page notes, however, you and your users get additional features if they use a Google+ account and the Google+ Sign-in, but this is not necessary.

The scopes required are

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` for name and gender
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` for the user's email address

**Update**: I should amend that these scopes are now deprecated, and scheduled for removal. See the URL above for details.

Comment: Could you shed some light here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010509/login-to-google-on-a-web-service-and-use-the-credentials-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't confuse a "gmail" account and a "Google+" account as being different things. Really what you want is for a user to authenticate with their "Google account", which spans many services.

On Android, the easiest way to build [authentication with Google accounts is to use the Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html), which includes services like Google sign in.

Google+ documents an end-to-end approach to using Google Play Services SDKs that cover the issues that you asked about by using the `PlusClient`:

1. [Setting up the client](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)
2. [Getting the user's email address](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address) using either `PlusClient.getAccountName()` or the REST methods.
3. [Getting the user's profile info](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information) using the `PlusClient.loadPerson()`

Comment: Isn't `getAccounts()` good to go with? where I can get gmail ids, so that i can use them to get the Access Token and then details. Because i tried it and i never needed any `PlusClient`, So, probably no chance of asking for a `Google+ profile`? It will be great if you can confirm on this :)

Comment: Because my major problem now is **If a Gmail Account doesn't have Google plus profile, it asks to create one. Which shouldn't happen. Gmail alone must be enough to get the Access Token and profile details**